# php function doesn't return value to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, function

I'm trying to call php function "funct1()" from javascript. I'm calling javascript function "clicked()" from button onclick. The problem is when i click the button in php  function doesn't return value to "someVariable".

```
<?php
function funct1()
{
    if(isset($_GET['cmbcode']))
    {
        $name = $_GET['cmbcode']; 
        echo $name; 
    }
}
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function clicked() 
    {
        var someVariable="<?php echo funct1(); ?>";
        alert(someVariable);

    }
</script>
```

Comment: you should return the $name and not echo inside the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are not returning the `$name` variable in your funct1() function it will not work with `echo` because it acts towards it as a variable.

Change your code to either return `$name` and then `echo` it using `echo funct1()` or just run `funct1()` without the `echo` (`var someVariable="<?php funct1(); ?>";`)